# Google sheet get api response limits

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Can somebody please help me in finding **official limits of [Google Spreadsheet api](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get) "RESPONSE"**.

Is it size based or num of cell based. I have to pull Grid data for number of columns from a quite big google sheet(30*57000).
But it fails to respond if I pull range of more then 18 columns in single request.
The error I receives

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 502 Bad Gateway
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 502 (Server Error)!!1</title>
  <style>
    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}
  </style>
  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
  <p><b>502.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
  <p>The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request.<p>Please try again in 30 seconds.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>`
```

Get request looks like:

```
{fields=sheets.data.rowData.values.effectiveFormat, ranges=[Sheet1!A2:A, Sheet1!M2:M, Sheet1!N2:N, Sheet1!O2:O, Sheet1!R2:R, Sheet1!S2:S, Sheet1!T2:T, Sheet1!U2:U, Sheet1!V2:V, Sheet1!X2:X, Sheet1!Y2:Y, Sheet1!Z2:Z, Sheet1!AC2:AC, Sheet1!AD2:AD, Sheet1!AE2:AE, Sheet1!AF2:AF, Sheet1!AG2:AG, Sheet1!AH2:AH, Sheet1!AI2:AI, Sheet1!AJ2:AJ], spreadsheetId=1_qVz-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXrXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}
```

Comment: Hi there @A_01! I tried to replicate this situation, but so far I am not able. To prevent a mismatching Sheet, please share yours so we all can take a look. Please remember to delete any private information beforehand.

Comment: with how big of a sheet you tried it? I will try to share it in sometime.

Comment: 1CnbAUEdtR_oMzs2StNRzsuy3kscaasdsaxkijbFw3Ug 
@Jacques-GuzelHeron you can check this.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your example I was able to replicate the behaviour. That 502 appears when getting huge ranges while including the grid data in the response. In order to prevent this issue the docs lists [«*For large spreadsheets, it is recommended to retrieve only the specific fields of the spreadsheet that you want*»](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get). Based on that approach, I strongly suggest you to get only the relevant ranges for the operation at hand. If you really need to get 18 columns (each with 57,457 rows), then you should spread your requests in several batches. Then you could join the responses so you could have a big array to interact with. Please ask me to clarify any point if needed.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. And I already started my implemetation to process in batches. But I am still wondering what is the official limits of these google sheet api response. I think its no where mentioned in there platform.